# Web Part Type for Existing Web Part

Tags: web-part

When you add a web part the default title tells you what type of part it is.  However once you change the title, it is not obvious what the web part is.  How do you find out what type of web part and existing one is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to put the page in to "maintenance" mode by simply adding "contents=1" in the query string.  So for example:

http://sharepoint.yours.com/site/pages/page.aspx?**contents=1**

Then, you will see the types of web parts on the page.

[image]

Comment: What if I only have owner access to this site.  I'm the nerd in my department but im not IT. edit I read this at home, I should try this at my work computer tomorrow before assuming maintenance mode is out of my permission level

Comment: If you are able to add and remove web parts on a page now, then you have access to this maintenance page.